# AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I have a struct:

```
struct server
{
    ssize_t (*handler)(char *, void*);
};
typedef struct server server;
```

In another function I assign the function pointer as follows,

```
void setHandler(server *s, ssize_t (*handler)(char *, void*)){
    s->handler = handler;
}
```

And to call the function pointer,

```
void perform(server *s){
    .
    .
    (s->handler)(path, NULL);
    .
    .
}
```

But I get the following AddressSanitizer error,

```
AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60200000eff8 at pc 0x0000004b111e bp 0x7fffd76687e0 sp 0x7fffd76687d0\nWRITE of size 8 at 0x60200000eff8 thread T0\n    #0 0x4b111d in setHandler /home/vmuser_xghkzivu/workspace/server_main.c:179\n
```

My code seems to go with all other examples I referred to, but am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: What does `s` point to?

Comment: can u show all source code?

Comment: "s" would be something like "struct server *s". The code is huge, not sure what else to post. Anything specific that maybe is needed and missing out on posting? But the only place I have modified the function pointer, that i have added in the post.

Comment: The code you have included is correct, so it is impossible to find the error from just those pieces of code. AddressSanitizer gives you the exact location of the error (`pc 0x4b111e`) - please include *that* code!

Comment: If this is correct, maybe it is an issue with the parameters I am passing... Will update the question with the source code